# How do I make my entity model give me access to my many-to-many tables?

Tags: c#, entity-framework, linq-to-entities

My model turns my join tables into a many-to-many relationship in the model editor. This means that when I query a table through the many-to-many relationship to a row in the other table, I get the `EntityCollection` instead of `IQueryable`.

It is my understanding that it is more efficient to stick with `IQueryable` because EntityCollection loads instances of the entity classes into memory then queries those.

Comment: I'm guessing you are using DB First approach?

Comment: Yes. Have you used both DB first and code first approaches? I'm curious as I've never tried DB first.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure it's exactly what you're looking for, but `EntityCollection<T>.CreateSourceQuery()` will return a new instance of `ObjectQuery`, which implements `IQueryable<T>`.

Answer (score 0):

Check out http://www.asp.net/entity-framework/tutorials/creating-a-more-complex-data-model-for-an-asp-net-mvc-application and look in the Customizing the Database Context section. There is a fluent API example of how to use join tables on many-to-many relationships. When I have a DB already defined, I like to create my own model classes and use Fluent API and Data Annotations to link them to the appropriate tables. That way I control how the application uses those tables instead of trusting the framework to build the way it thinks it needs to be built. This does two things: 1) It ensures that you are familiar with how the app uses your data, and 2) gives you more control over how data is represented in the app.

Happy coding!